# Preprocessor Macro : Make pointer from integer content

Tags: pointers, macros, embedded, avr

I would like to make a preprocessor macro which converts an integer representing an address into a pointer. This is for MCU development.

For example, registers are defined like

```
#define SOME_REGISTER 0x05 // This the the address of SOME_REGISTER
```

So I have defined the following macro:

```
#define REG_ADDR(reg) (*((volatile uint8_t*) reg))
```

And when I wan't to use it

```
volatile uint8_t * reg_ptr = REG_ADDR(SOME_REGISTER)
```

But of course, I get the `makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]` warning

Is there a clean way to do that ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: I think the first asterisk in your definition of `REG_ADDR` should be deleted.  Isn't that dereferencing the pointer you just created by casting `reg`?  That's not what you're trying to do, is it?

Comment: What register are you trying to access, and what AVR are you using?  Doesn't your AVR toolchain already provide a definition for the register if you include `avr/io.h` at the top of your program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you'd simply define such registers as `#define SOME_REGISTER (*(volatile uint8_t*) 0x05)` without the extra step.

The compiler message comes because the macro is written with a `*` de-reference so that it can be used just as a regular variable. So you'd read/write directly to the register, without no local pointer variable in between.

If that's not what you want, then either don't use the register like that, or change the code to this:

```
volatile uint8_t* reg_ptr = &REG_ADDR(SOME_REGISTER);
```

The `&` at the caller and the `*` inside the macro will cancel each other out.

Comment: Thanks for your clear anwser, I missused register, now it's clearer.

Comment: That "extra step" might come in handy in assembly language files, as a simple `#define` for a register number can be used in `.S` source files.

Comment: @ndim That's very much tool chain-specific.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-use already existing, proven code released with the proper license.
You may for example use [mmio.h](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/blob/master/include/lib/mmio.h) code from Arm, you can find it in the git repository for the Arm Trusted Firmware, in the `include/lib` directory.

In your example, you would use the `mmio_read_8()` function from `mmio.h`:

```
static inline uint8_t mmio_read_8(uintptr_t addr)
{
    return *(volatile uint8_t*)addr;
}
```

Resulting code would be:

```
volatile uint8_t * reg_ptr = mmio_read_8((uintptr_t) SOME_REGISTER);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I'm going to test that.

Comment: Writing directly to hardware registers isn't rocket science, it's everyday bread & butter embedded programming. There is no need for 3rd party bloatware to do such trivial things. If anything, use the register map given by the tool vendor for the specific part.

Comment: Also, this so-called "trusted lib" is full of fishy implicit type promotions. Might work fine on 32 bitters and then cough up subtle bugs on 8 bitters. Never trust "smart" one-liners that contain some 4-5 silent implicit type conversions on the same line. That's brittle code, a minimum of MISRA-C compliance would weed out all these potential hazards.

Comment: @Lundin: I would say that if this were that trivial for our friend, he would probably not even have asked his question at the first place, even though the answer may seem trivial to you and me. On the other side, the guys at Arm probably know what they are doing, but they still made the choice to reuse an existing header file they had at their disposal, and this is a respectable choice UMHO.

Comment: @Lundin: Whatever code will be used in our friend's application will ultimately  have to be tested. I still consider re-using mmio.h is safer for a beginner than to use his own code, but I agree this may be subjective.

Comment: Yeah, don't use external libraries to do things that are basic language features.  Reading licenses and complying with them is a big pain.  I wouldn't use a library to add two ints, so I wouldn't use a library to write to a hardware register.  Also, avr-gcc comes with a bunch of header files that show how to define hardware registers.  Those headers use a simple approach much like what the OP is trying to do, so that approach seems appropriate.

Comment: @David Grayson: I had missed the `avr` tag, but this is  exactly what I was meaning by "re-use already existing, proven code".